# Apply filter on collection Object

Tags: magento

I am getting this object on list page

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

//return 3 records
```

now I applied filter as

```
$_productCollection=$_productCollection->addFieldToFilter('genre', array('finset' => '126'));

//now it should return 1 record
```

but it gives me a count of 3. Now, if I run the query in database by getting the query using echo `$_productCollection->getSelect();` it returns 1 record.

Can anybody help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely this doesn't work because `$this->getLoadedProductCollection()` returns a collection which *already has been loaded* by the `catalog/layer` singleton.

But you could override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection()` to get in control and add the custom filters you want.

Comment: Can you please explain it according to my problem as I am unable to embed it in my code

Comment: @Curiologix: what problems do you face when embedding it in your code?